# Use global functions in vue directives

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use lodash methods (`_.isEmpty`) in vue directives like this:

```
<div class="post" v-for="post in posts"></div>
    ...
    <div class="comments" v-if="! _.isEmpty(post.comments)">
      <div class="comment" v-for="comment in post.comments"></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

but getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined

It seems vue is looking for the `_.isEmpty` method inside the current scope. How should I call global functions in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only access functions of the current Vue instance/component in a template:

- data
- props
- methods

No "third-party" code can be run.

So, you would have to create a method in the Vue component to proxy to the lodash methods:

```
methods: {
  isEmpty: function (arr) { return _.isEmpty(arr)}
}
```

and use this method in the template instead:

```
<div class="comments" v-if="! isEmpty(post.comments)">
```

Comment: As a newcomer to vue.js, that broke my heart!

Comment: Well, it's intentional: business logic does not belong in the template. It's a nightmare to debug and refactor. Of course, a sweet short little lodash function wont do much harm, but the system can't or shouldn't make exeptions for sweet little lodash functions ;). That being said, you could probably inject lodash into Vue as an instance method: `Vue.prototype._ = _`, that should allow you to access it in the view as `_` - but  I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add `_` to your Vue component:

```
data(){
  return {
    _:require('lodash')  //or however you include it. maybe just window._
  }
}
```

Then it would be accessible.  Not positive if `_` is a valid object key, so might just call it `lo` or `lodash` if needed.

Also, assuming that comments is an array, there would be no problem using `v-if='post.comments.length'`.  Lo-dash is great but unnecessary if you already know it's an array.